# DataTable.WriteXml does not write the type of columns

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I found that `DataTable.WriteXml()`does **not** write the type of columns into the generated XML code! So how can I distinguish between 32 and 64-bit integers?

Here is my code:

```
Int32 i32 = 12345678;
Int64 i64 = 12345678901234567;

DataTable p = new DataTable();
p.TableName = "Parameters";

p.Columns.Add("ColInt", i32.GetType());
p.Columns.Add("ColLong", i64.GetType());

DataRow r = p.NewRow();
r["ColInt"] = i32;
r["ColLong"] = i64;
p.Rows.Add(r);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
p.WriteXml(sw);
string x = sw.ToString();
```

And this is the XML output. You can clearly see that the type of the two columns (ColInt, ColLong) is not written to the XML code!

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Parameters>
    <ColInt>12345678</ColInt>
    <ColLong>12345678901234567</ColLong>
  </Parameters>
</DocumentElement>
```

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` as parameter for `WriteXml` method.

```
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            p.WriteXml(sw, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            string x = sw.ToString();
```

It gives the below xml data with its schema.

```
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Parameters" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Parameters">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ColInt" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ColLong" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Parameters>
    <ColInt>12345678</ColInt>
    <ColLong>12345678901234567</ColLong>
  </Parameters>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: @askolotl checkout this whether this works for you ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly!! Also tried to create a second table with ReadXml(), and it re-creates the table absolutely correctly.

Comment: @askolotl glad to help you !!